ansible not respecting timeout values in ansible.cfg
config file is:
[defaults]
inventory = inventory
host_key_checking = False
deprecation_warnings=False
forks = 200
display_skipped_hosts = false
retry_files_enabled = True
vars_plugins = plugins/vars
filter_plugins = plugins/filter
terminal_plugins = plugins/terminal
cliconf_plugins = plugins/cliconf
action_plugins = plugins/action
ansible_timeout = 300
timeout = 300
[persistent_connection]
command_timeout = 300
connect_timeout = 300
persistent_command_timeout = 300
persistent_connect_timeout = 300

I have some long running tasks that use SSH that fail after 100 seconds
"msg": "command timeout triggered, timeout value is 100 secs.\nSee the timeout setting options in the Network Debug and Troubleshooting Guide."

There is no other timeout value configured anywhere in the playbook.  Using ansible [core 2.17.4]
Any ideas? i've tried every timeout setting i can find

Your timeout settings from ansible.cfg are not being applied OR are being overridden somewhere else.
I would make sure ansible_command_timeout is not set anywhere in your playbooks / roles / inventory.
cd <root_of_your_ansible_repo>
grep -r ansible_command_timeout

Also make sure to check your env, ansible settings set via environment variables will take precedence over ansible.cfg , i.e. ANSIBLE_PERSISTENT_COMMAND_TIMEOUT
Last but not least. Make sure your ansible.cfg is actually read by ansible-playbook. Sounds obvious but can be an issue depending on your execution environment.
Sources:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/general_precedence.html#configuration-settings
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/user_guide/network_debug_troubleshooting.html#timeout-issues

